# jQuery var not being sent with Uploadify

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I have the following code block. Uploadify itself works fine, however the custom form data that's sending the jquery variable isn't sending to the script at all. Yet if i set it to 1 or some basic text, it works fine. Am i missing something really simple? The alert on complete shows the data fine.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

            var scheduledImageDesc = '';
            $('#scheduledImageDesc').on("keyup change", function(e) {
                scheduledImageDesc = $(this).val();
            });

            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'formData'      : {
                    'scheduledImageDesc': scheduledImageDesc,
                    'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                },
                'buttonText'    : 'Upload New Image',
                'swf'           : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader'      : 'uploadify/uploadifyScheduledImage.php',
                'fileExt'       : '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.JPG; *.JPEG;',
                'multi'         : true,
                'auto'          : true,
                'fileSizeLimit' : '4MB',
                //'checkExisting' : 'uploadify/check-exists-scheduled-image.php',
                'onQueueComplete' : function(data) { 
                    //location.reload();
                    alert(scheduledImageDesc);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: View source. What's the JS come out as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, i had to add in another function in order to get the update from the input field i was using before it sent it. If anyone else ever gets stuck, here's what worked for me.

jQuery:

```
var scheduledImageDesc = '';
            $('#scheduledImageDesc').on("keyup change", function(e) {
                scheduledImageDesc = $(this).val();
            });

            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'formData'      : {
                    'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                },
                'buttonText'    : 'Upload New Image',
                'swf'           : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader'      : 'uploadify/uploadifyScheduledImage.php',
                'fileExt'       : '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.JPG; *.JPEG;',
                'multi'         : true,
                'auto'          : true,
                'fileSizeLimit' : '4MB',
                'onUploadStart' : function(file) {

                    $("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", "formData", {"scheduledImageDesc": scheduledImageDesc});

                },
                //'checkExisting' : 'uploadify/check-exists-scheduled-image.php',
                'onQueueComplete' : function(data) { 
                    //location.reload();
                    alert(scheduledImageDesc);
                }
            });
```